# If argument is blank do not append to string

Tags: javascript

I want to write a simple javascript function to append to a string of values given arguments, but only if the arguments have values.  Here is an example:

```js
function foo(bar){
  return "hello" + bar;  
}
```

If I run `foo()` I will get "helloundefined" I want it to just return "hello" and if i run `foo('world')` that works right now with "helloworld"

I was thinking I could do something like:

`return "hello" + null || bar` but i would just get "hellonull"

or

`return "hello" + if(bar){bar}` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `return 'hello' + (bar || '');`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put parenthesis!  Thank you.  Add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good "clean" way (for which the logic is identical across languages) of doing this is to test your input:

```
function foo(bar){
  if (bar) {
    return "hello" + bar;  
  }
  return "hello";
}
```

then you can use the traditional ternary operator's expression, which is quite ugly:

```
 function foo(bar) {
   return "hello" + (bar ? bar : '');
 }
```

but the usual, common and widely used javascript one liner idiom to do the exact same thing is:

```
function foo(bar) {
  return "hello" + (bar || '');
}
```

Because it's more concise it is *very* widely used. But I'd prefer option 1 for readability/accessibility of the code, even if it's more characters to be written (we're doing code, not golf, and code needs to be readable for others. And sometime the "others" is you in six months).

edit:

Just for completing my answer, I'll add @oriol suggestion:

```
function foo(bar = ''){
  return "hello" + bar;  
}
```

Which actually is concise *and* elegant. To be used wherever you can run ES6!

Answer (score 3):

In ECMAScript 6, you can use [default paramenters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```js
function foo(bar = ''){
  return "hello" + bar;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? It uses the ternary operator (shorthand if else).

What it will output through the `alert` is:

*Hello*

then

*Hello Script47*

```
function foo(bar) 
{
    return bar.trim() != "" ? "Hello " + bar : "Hello";
}

alert(foo(""));

alert(foo("Script47"));
```

I use `trim` to prevent white spaces.

http://jsfiddle.net/7oukdaty/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `argument` is present first.

```js
function hello(bar) {
  var p = document.getElementById("foo");
  if (bar) {
    p.innerHTML = "hello" + bar;
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = "hello";
  }
}

hello("world");
```

```html
<p id="foo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator:

```
function foo(bar){
    return "hello" + (bar ? bar : '');  
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the argument is null and do whatever you want.

```
function foo(bar) {
    if (!bar) {
        alert("no bar defined");
    }
    else {
        alert("hello" + bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, when an argument is not passed, its value is `undefined`, not `null`. Here it works because the loose `==` is used, but it wouldn't work with `===`.

Comment: Douglas Crockford would shun me.